# JFrame/JPanel not updating while running process

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, repaint

I have a `Process` running (gradew deploy for FRC) and I have its output directed into a `BufferedReader`, and a `JFrame` (`parent` in the below block) for a new window with a `JPanel` containing a `JTextArea` (`outputArea`). I had, initially, this method to update the text area while reading the output from the `Process`:

```
public void show(BufferedReader in){
    outputArea.setText("");

    while(true){
        String line = in.readLine();

        if(line == null){
            break;
        }

        outputArea.append(line + "\n");
    }

    parent.setTitle("Deploy Output");
}
```

This implementation showed a blank window while the `Process` was running, and only updated to the output after it completed.
Currently, to try to get it to update, I have, where the `Process` and window are created, the following loop and the subsequent method:

```
while(!outputWindow.getDone()){ //getDone returns done as set in the subsequent method
    outputWindow.show(br); //br = the BufferedReader
    outputWindow.repaint();
}
```

```
public void show(BufferedReader in){
    String line = in.readLine();

    if(line == null){
        parent.setTitle("Deploy Output");
        done = true;
        return;
    }

    outputArea.append(line + "\n");
}
```

Other things I have tried include using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` with the `repaint`, creating a new thread with the `repaint`, and using `revalidate` along with the `repaint`. According to a little debugging by printing during each iteration of this version's while loop shows that it is getting output before it updates, but it only shows both the text and the other components of the frame after the `Process` finishes.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Edit (almost forgot) - A Github repository for the full project is here, where it has the first version of the method: [Github](https://github.com/cadet-robotics/2019-Config-Editor)

Comment: This certainly is a duplicate, but I don't know the best one to point to right now, so here's the relevant tutorial link, at least: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html tl;dr: The Swing Event Dispatch Thread (which is responsible for repainting the UI) is blocked while it is busy with reading the input stream. You'll have to do this in a separate thread.

Comment: @Marco13 I know its pretty similar to a lot of others, but I couldn't find anything closely matching my case

Comment: Just to clarify: When you mention a "Process", you're talking about an actual https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html right?

Comment: 1) *"anything closely matching"* Anything that blocks the EDT closely matches this. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Marco13 Yes. Specifically, its running a gradlew deploy for FRC